# Import Not Found Error in Docker but not while running locally

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker

I made an 'importTest.py' to troubleshoot. It only has the following code:

```
try:
    import PackageA.DeviceController
    print("Success")

except ImportError:
    print("fail")
```

This works locally, but when running in a docker container I get an `ImportError`. 'PackageA/DeviceController.py' is a local file inside the same directory as 'importTest.py'. (they are both in 'PackageA', which has an empty **init**.py aswell).
 When entering the bash from the docker container, and entering 
'python3 --> import packageA.DeviceController'
this also works but doesn't work when running the script. Does anyone know the reason and how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Your local machine has the dependencies installed, but your Docker container does not.
You can use a [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) to install the necessary requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the dependecies inside the docker machine.

Comment: packageA is a local class inside the same directory as 'importTest.py'.